# Any way to obtain additional information about io_service

Tags: c++, boost-asio

While trying to hack clean shutdown of asio app I find it quite irritating that I cant know if ios stopped because i called .stop() or because it run out of handlers.
Also when I want to kill it I cant find a way to see if it has handler in its handlers q, or even if some handlers are running atm.
So
1) Any way to see what stopped ios - .stop or running out of work (except the awful manual bIsAppShuttingDown flag )
2) Any way to see if io_service (after I called stop) is still processing something?
so I can write

```
ios->stop()
while(! ios.finished())
sleep(1) // :/
delete ios;
```

Comment: Well, if you stop() the io_service, all outstanding async operations should call their handler with the operation_aborted error code, so you could check that way whether the io_service was stopped or ran out of work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically the pattern is to dispatch on the io_service in a separate thread, for example:

```
_thread.reset(new std::thread([&]() { _service.run(); }); // so the dispatching here is in a thread
```

Subsequently, if you want to stop it and wait for it to finish cleanly, then the best way is:

```
_service.stop();
_thread->join();
```

This way the calling thread is blocked until the dispatch thread terminates (which happens when the call to execute the last handler (`run()`) completes. There is no way (AFAIK) of knowing whether the io_service ran out of work or whether `stop()` was called, you can certainly prevent the former by instantiating an `io_service::work` on the service. See the docs.